# Question mark in URL of a wordpress post

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress for my blog. I tried to add a new post in my native language(Tamil). Everything was successful except the URL. My permalink will have the post title and post id in the URL. But for this specific post which post title in tamil having issue with the URL. The URL automatically changing to question mark wherever the tamil words are coming. For example,

[http://www.example.com/12/ச](http://www.example.com/12/%E0%AE%9A)ாம்பிள்-போஸ்ட்/ is changing to http://www.example.com/12/?-???/

Please help.

Comment: It is showing correctly for me. Tamil URLs are supported nowadays, not just the file names or page names. So, even a domain like `http://என்தளம்.இந்தியா` will work. You might have old version of browser or app, or you need to change your settings such that encoding is set to UTF-8

Comment: One example to show you. In my PC, the below URL works correctly.          https://ranjaninarayanan.wordpress.com/tag/%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%B2%E0%AF%88%E0%AE%AA%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%AA%E0%AF%82/      which OS, browser? Give more details. Or, are you trying with any programming languages or apps?

Comment: Thanks guys. It works now. I dont know which exactly made this to work.

Comment: Post the answer once you find enough details to explain.

Comment: I dont know actually. I did many things like changing mysql settings, worpress settings.